# the permutations of some numbers, especially some common numbers in input

Tags: numbers, duplicates, permutation

just like the input is : 1,2,2,3,4,5. I have to work out all the permutations of these numbers, just pay attention that 2 is a duplicate number.

```
private static void perm1(String prefix, String s) {
    int N = s.length();
    if (N == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
           perm1(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, N));
    }
```

Comment: Cool. What's the question?

Comment: give you six numbers just like :1,2,2,3,4,5  you have to write a main function in java, the out put is the all the different permutations of the five numbers . like 122345, 212345. while the most important condition is that you will never print the duplicate permutation. thanks Matt.

Comment: yes  i tried, i always print the duplicate permutation, i don't know why, this is not a homework it is a interview question.

Comment: Well, post your code then and the community can help step through your logic. It's even more important that you do this if this really is an interview question. I can almost guarantee you'll get harder questions than that and it's crucial that you can think through problems on your own.

Comment: OK, thank you Matt .